# Disable AVX-512 Intrinsics in VS 2017

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, intrinsics, avx512

I don't own a Xeon Phi and don't intend coding for one. Therefore, until AVX-512 becomes mainstream (rumored to be the case from Intel Gen 9 onward), these intrinsics are of no use to me.

AVX/2 lacks `_mm_cvtepi64_epi32`, for example, which exists in AVX-512. I'd like to write this as a function (using shuffle). However, I can't use this name since it's defined in "zmmintrin.h". That header is linked to from a header I link to.

I know the simple solution is to use another name. That would break the naming convention, though.

Is there a way to either override the name or somehow disable AVX-512 in my project?

Comment: You could always use CPP macros to `#define _mm_cvtepi64_epi32 NO512_emulated_mm_cvtepi64_epi32`, if you want to write code using the intrinsic.  But do you really need this?  In this case the emulation only takes one `pshufd` (if you don't care about leaving garbage in the high elements), but in other cases it's probably better to design your vectorization around what AVX2 can do efficiently.  AVX2-only or SSE4-only will be relevant for a *long* time even after the first mainstream desktop / laptop chips with AVX512 are released (Cannonlake, hopefully early 2019).

Comment: If you just want to make sure you didn't accidentally use any AVX-512 intrinsics, compile with gcc or clang with `-march=skylake` (not `-march=skylake-avx512`).  Those compilers won't allow intrinsics for instruction-sets that aren't enabled, even if you include the relevant headers (`immintrin.h`)

Comment: I'm in Visual Studio, though.

Comment: Right, so compiling with gcc or clang isn't super convenient, but it's possible if your code is portable.  Not sure if you can set up either of those compilers to run from within your IDE.  Unfortunately Intel's compiler behaves like MSVC, and accepts intrinsics even if you haven't used `-march`, which is too bad because it's more MSVC-compatible.

Comment: The odd thing in VS is one has to specify if AVX or AVX2 are usable. AVX512 isn't even mentioned in the settings. However, whatever is specified does not prevent illegal intrinsics from being compiled. Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Anyway, IMO the best answer is just "don't use that name" most of the time.  Are you finding a lot of cases where you want to compile the same function into an AVX2 and an AVX512 version, e.g. avoiding 512-bit vectors with AVX512 because of possible max-turbo limitations and execution-port limits?  It's not obvious that there's a lot of use for one AVX512 instruction in a function that's otherwise written to run on CPUs with only AVX2.  And if you don't want to eventually compile as AVX512 for a speedup, then just use different names.  And yes, MSVC doesn't make sense in a lot of ways.

Comment: I decided to go the wild route and append an underscore on the name. I've only come across 1 AVX-512 reserved name so far. All things being equal, I have to say VS 2017 has come a long way and is quite the marvel in many ways. Naturally it will have edges.

Comment: I'd be more inclined to *omit* the leading underscore for helper functions I wrote myself.  And BTW, you might want to use a C++ wrapper library around the intrinsics.  Agner Fog's VCL is nice (http://agner.org/optimize/), but it's GPLed so it's not applicable to closed-source projects that distribute binaries.  It makes it easy to template a function on the vector width so you can build 128-bit / AVX2 / AVX512 versions, instead of needing different function names as well as different types.

Comment: I'm adding the _ on the end and noting in the header that it's an "override". Interesting point you make about omitting the _ from the beginning. I can see why that's a good idea. I still like the way `_mm256_absdiff_ps` and `_mm256_clamp_ps_roundhalfawayfromzero_cvt_epi32` look, though :).

Comment: Ugh, `_mm_` is already overly verbose compared to asm mnemonics.  Redundant naming like `_mm256_load_si256` just looks ugly to me compared to `vmovdqa ymm`, but it is what it is.  I guess maybe it's nice for IDE auto-completion to have a consistent prefix.  I'm not sure `mm_foo_ps` mixed in with `_mm_add_ps` would look better; what I've actually done in the past is leave off the prefix noise entirely, and name it like `float hsum_ps(__m128)`, especially for functions which are more than one instruction long even after inlining and hoisting constants out of loops.

Comment: I guess it comes down to familiarity and intent. The ASM instructions are rather cryptic as first, but arguably no more difficult to use than the intrinsics. Since we're not hand coding ASM, I suppose the intent is to have more "human readable" names, which cold head us in the direction of regular function names. The problem is that someone (or ourselves) needs to understand the code later on. I've learned not to be *too* cryptic. But I also generally dislike long names (except in this case where it seems to make sense).

Comment: I don't see that `_mm256_permutexvar_epi32` is a lot more readable than [`vpermd`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/VPERMD:VPERMW.html).  I'd have been happy with `_mm256_permute_epi32`.  But Intel had to make things confusing by using the `_mm256_permute_ps`  / permutevar name for AVX1 `vpermilps` (in-lane permute).  I have to know the asm mnemonics already to check the compiler output and make sure loops optimized nicely, and to read the best documentation on what each instruction does (the asm ref manual), and to get the most out of performance counters / static analysis for the pipeline.

Comment: The *length* of the intrinsic names is a minor annoyance, but for me the biggest annoyance is when they diverge too much from the asm mnemonics.  When I'm thinking about a problem, I think about what asm can do efficiently, then write it in intrinsics.  Especially for SSE (without AVX), thinking in asm lets you write code that avoids unnecessary `movda` register-copy instructions by choosing non-destructive copy-and-shuffles like `pshufd` instead of right-shift by bytes like `_mm_srli_si128` / `psrldq`.  Intrinsics also need to work in C without overloading, though, so permute vs. permutevar..

Comment: You're correct. But, you're in the upper 0.001% in this field. That's a different context. You read ASM. Most developers don't. Having said that, IMO Intel has made the whole scene as confusing as possible. The naming is inconsistent. Simple operations are obscure, while complex ones are clear. It's often not at all obvious how to do something simple. All solved with experience, for sure.

Comment: @PeterCordes [Cannonlake is out. (albeit with single-ported FMA)](https://www.zhihu.com/question/277156338) But unless you're in China, you'll need to go out of your way to get one. Don't expect any of the CNLs to have dual-ported FMA since they're going to be low-end laptop only. So we're talking more like late-2019/2020 for server Ice Lake with dual-FMA.

Comment: @Mysticial: Oh, I hadn't heard Intel was ditching plans for desktop CNL.  Why do you mention *server* Ice Lake?  We're talking about when i3/i5/i7 mainstream laptops / desktops will have any AVX512, at which point it could be useful for games / photoshop / etc. to include some AVX512 code paths.  Maybe for integer code, and/or limited to 256-bit vectors to avoid turbo limits and port1 shutdown while still taking advantage of new instructions and the nice mask-register features.  512-bit FMA throughput is far from the only cool thing about AVX512 for many use-cases other than Prime95 :P

Comment: Oh I mean that it's unlikely that dual-ported AVX512 will show up in any non-server die any time soon. I won't be surprised if Intel keeps it out of the non-server dies until there's a real need for it.

Comment: To be clear, chips without dual ported 512-bit FMA, still have two 512-bit units which operate for most other instructions, right?

Comment: @PeterCordes They probably ditched it because of the 10nm problems. I found out a year ago that they would skip the server line for CNL. Now all the pieces fall together. Because of the problems with 10nm, CNL got reduced to low-end laptop only (the smallest die). All the high-end stuff got rolled up into ICL which will go out on the more refined 10nm+ which will hopefully have high enough yields to do larger dies.

Comment: @BeeOnRope Correct. But "most other instructions" means non-multiplication integer. All floating-point (including FP-Add), integer multiplication, and int <-> float conversions use the FMA and will be halved.

Comment: Thanks @Mysticial! Those are the ones that matter to me :).

Comment: @Mysticial: Is there a detailed / exhaustive list of what uops use an FMA unit (or instlatx64 results for a CPU with only one 512-bit FMA unit)?  Probably almost everything that deals with FP and runs with 4c latency on p01, right?  So that would cover `vcmpps` and `vmin/maxps`, and *maybe* also the 2 uops from `vroundps` (there's no 512-bit form of `vroundps`, but 256-bit `vroundps` mixed with 512-bit instructions would be affected, right?)  I guess also AVX512 `VRNDSCALEPS`.  Hmm, maybe even 16-bit integer mul, because  `pmulhuw` / `pmaddwd` are 5c latency on p01.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, compare the InstLatx64 numbers for single vs. dual port FMA. But given an instruction, it's quite easily figure it out without having to look it up. 1) Does it do multiplication? It needs the FMA. 2) Does it interpret an FP exponent/mantissa? It needs the FMA. 3) Does it do FP normalization and mantissa shifting? It needs the FMA.

Comment: The only ones that don't quite fit the picture are the super-slow FPU instructions (division + square root) since those have special hardware on port0+1. `vround` and `vrndscale` are 2 uops since they might be implemented as a normalize + denormalize. You can (almost) emulate either instruction with a `vadd` and `vsub` by a magic constant - missing only a couple of overflow corner cases.

Comment: @Mysticial: Thanks, I found the http://instlatx64.atw.hu/ results you were talking about by searching on Bronze on that page.  I forget what I'd tried searching on before that didn't find a one-FMA result.  It wasn't totally obvious that unusual/funky integer mul insns wouldn't have their own unit, like `vpmaddwd` or VPMADDUBSW, VPMULHRSW.  It does make sense that they'd attach the necessary shifter / horizontal-add / whatever stuff to 16-bit chunks of multiplier hardware in the FMA unit, but I wasn't sure how easy that was at a gate level.